# How to test a simple rescue block in ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, puppet, rescue

I have a custom fact in ruby that goes like this:

```
Facter.add(:some_random_fact) do
  setcode do
    output = execute_some_method
    if !output.nil? then
      begin
        pruned_output = output.split("\n")
        result = true
      rescue
        result = false
      end
    else
      result = false
    end
  end
end
```

How do I write a unit test using rspec for the rescue block to raise an Exception?

EDIT: Please let me know if the below test is the correct way to test it

```
it "return fact as false when begin block raises exception" do
    output = double(:output)
    allow(output).to receive(:split).with(true).and_raise(RuntimeError.new("error occured"))
    expect(Facter.fact(:some_random_fact).vallue).to eq(false)
end
```

Comment: I would try to assign `nil` to `output` before running the spec because `nil.spilt` would raise a `NoMethodError (undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass)`.

Comment: Your example code seems to be quite incomplete. For example, there are assignments but the variables aren't used afterwards. You'll likely get better answers if you show your actual code. (you can probably avoid the exception handling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've shown here is weird and I get the feeling we're missing context, but in general you can stub out a method to raise an error like so:

```
expect(output).to receive(:split).with("\n").and_raise(RuntimeError.new("some error"))
```

but this is sort of an ugly way to go about things. If the error is raised conditionally depending the type of `output`, then it's better to find a way to set that variable to an error-producing value. How to do that, I can't tell you without seeing the test of your code.

For example, say you wrapped all this code in a `def add_fact(output)` - then from your tests you could intentionally pass an error-causing value for the `output`, and you no longer need to stub split (which is a wierd thing to do). This pattern is known as "dependency injection".